# Populate Date Dimension

Tags: ssis

I'm new to ssis.I want to extract Order Date from Database and store it in Dimension 'Date'

I found a link to populate the Date dim However, the process is done without considering any field from the source database

I couldn't find in internet how to populate date dimension using ssis tasks.Is it the same as populating other dim (ex.Customer) if yes, How do you select a date '01-02-12' and then stored as

- year
- semestre
- Month
- week
- day

I hope my question is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically date dimensions are shared dimensions, e.g. can be used by any date field in the fact tables. So this would be defined on its own, independent of any specific date field as you would want to have all dates in a time frame in it, not just dates for a specific business process. As for using SSIS for this process, you have many options. You could have a database view with the logic to define the dimension attributes in it, you could use derived columns with SSIS expressions, or you could do a script task. Probably the simplest solution is the derived column. You can find a list of the date time functions available in the derived column component here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141671.aspx